# Syncing Computer Description With Active Directory Description Field

Tags: windows, active-directory

After changing my computer description within windows and restarting the machine, the description field in active directory for that particular machine will not populate? Any tip/idea of what the problem may be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by design. The description box that you find in `Control Panel > System` is for use by the local computer only. It is not meant to sync automatically with AD.

You could synchronize them with some sort of script if you wanted to.

```
Set-ADComputer PC1 `
   -Description (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName PC1).Description
```

If you're actually on the computer you want to get the local computer's description for, omit the `-ComputerName` parameter from `Get-WMIObject`. That's for remote systems.)

To make this work, you'd need AD Web Services running on your domain controller (2008 R2 and above,) you'd need the AD Powershell cmdlets on your client, (the Remote Server Administration Tools come with these) and of course write permission to actually write to the description LDAP attribute of the desired computer object in AD.